# Cordova - Change app name accordingly to the build type

Tags: cordova

I need to change the app name of a `Cordova` based project depending on the gradle build type (debug/release). If I understand correctly, `Cordova` uses the `<name`tag in master `config.xml` as app name. Is there any easy way to configure it? If no, what should I use?

I am using `cordova-android": "^6.2.3`

Comment: Can you please look into this problem I could not solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513672/errorunable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebugandroidtest-compileclasspath @Blackbelt

Answer (score 3):

#### Below are the 3 ways to do so :

#### - Step 1:

You can set the name of your Application in your config.xml

the tag which defines it is

```
<name>your appname</name>
```

---

#### - Step 2 :

You actually need to go to `res` -> `values` -> `strings.xml` and change:

`<string name="app_name">Your app's name</string>`

---

#### - Step 3:

In cordova project> `properties`> `WMAppManifest.xml` file you can change you app's name and icon as well.

> If Still Issue :

Check this link - http://www.cordovacircus.com/articles/cordova-android-name

Comment: I am pretty new and very rookie to Cordova. From my tests `res/values/strings` is being ignored. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, in some cases, cordova is bit weird. That's why I told to try all of them one by one.

Comment: regarding step 1:  `<name>your appname</name>`, how can I tell `Cordova` to use `App Name Dev` when I am building using debug and `App Name Pro` when I am using release as buildType?

Comment: If I am understanding correct, you want to make different names for both the build versions ?

Comment: That's correct. When I use `cordova build android` I need to `App Name Dev` and when I use  `cordova build android --release` I need  `App Name Pro`

Comment: @Blackbelt please check [this](http://www.cordovacircus.com/articles/cordova-android-name)

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `android:label` attribute in your `<application>` tag in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file
Like this:

```
<application 
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
  android:icon="@mipmap/icon" 
  android:label="@string/app_name" <!--Replace with your Application name-->
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:allowBackup="false" 
  android:fullBackupContent="false">
```

Comment: he is asking to do in **cordova**

Comment: yes, i have recently tested in my cordova app so i post answer :-)

Comment: @Blackbelt that is what I was saying.

Comment: which cordova version you use? @Blackbelt

Comment: Is there a way to change the name of the app, for testing purposes on a device with `cordova run android` but adding a specific name for the app, to not replace an older version? Or there is a must in changing the `.xml` file?