# Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12

Tags: android, gradle

I create an new android project It shows errors on built

I tried the exiting answers

- [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7 24.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519515/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v7-24-0-1)
- I tried to invalidate and restart android studio

**Error are**

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   junit:junit:4.12.
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   junit:junit:4.12.
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   junit:junit:4.12.
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1.

Dependencies section of my gradle file

```
 dependencies 
    {
       implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    }
```

I do not understand it is my first my project.

My Project gradle is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android
        {
            configurations.all
                    {
                        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
                    }
        }

dependencies
        {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


}
```

Comment: Just remove everything related to Test compilers

Comment: I did but still got these errors @AlexJolig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to mix AppCompat and Jetpack dependencies, and you cannot do that.

I think I  might not have the right repository setup for the Jetpack libraries (why it can't find any Jetpack libraries).

Don't use: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' . (this is Jetpack) -- use AppCompat versions of this (besides - Jetpack is NOT consistent with Appcompat versions earlier then 28.x). Bottom line, get rid of anything that says (androidx).

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add below repository in your build.gradle file,

```
repositories {
      jcenter()
      maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

you forgot to add this to your dependencies

```
androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
```

The problem is caused by espresso library , if you can't remove it add this to your app gradle

```
android
{ 
 configurations.all 
  { 
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9' 
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194683/discussion-on-answer-by-ismail-alaoui-errorunable-to-resolve-dependency-for-a).

Comment: Adding maven fixed it for me. Weird that the issue was during the first build of the template project Android Studio comes with.